# Calculating many rows using a function

Tags: python, pandas, csv

Will like to ask u all how do I go about calculating returns or spread difference between each ID. Will like to use a function such as a define function etc.

Example: The difference between each **high** for id 1 and 2, The difference between each **close** for id 1 and 2.

Many thanks.

[image: Here is the image]

Comment: sure, noted though that doesnt answer the question.

Comment: @Jonathan: You could try using `diff()`.

Comment: hi Shaido, can i ask if i want to calculate spread how do i go about doing that?

Comment: Please do not post text like code, error messages, data as pictures, post it directly here on SO. Also, please read [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would convert your data into Pandas dataframe and use the `diff()` function. Is this you are looking for?

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'Open': [187.88, 185.14, 186.35, 187.25],
                   'High': [189.22, 186.33, 187.2, 188.35],
                   'Low': [187.2, 183.45, 185.73, 184.94]}, index=range(1, 5))
df.index.name = 'ID'
spread = df.diff()
```

Comment: Hello Pete, thanks so much for your reply. Actually its something like that but because i have about 500 rows of data, i'm not sure if i'm able to convert everything into a dataframe as such.

Comment: This is no problem, just convert your data to any readable format such as csv and use `df = pd.read_csv('file.csv')`

Comment: actually i've converted it to CSV format but i'm still unable to calculate row by row..

Comment: If you wish, post preferably the error message, otherwise anybody can't help you much.

Comment: will do Pete! Actually i've managed to get it already. Thanks a lot for your help!